# get image from html.file in python

Tags: python, html, get, screenshot, scrape

```
import os
import imgkit
imgkit.from_url('file.html', 'out.jpg')
```

HTML file

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_0a8c1"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSDT/?exchange=BINANCE" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">BTCUSDT Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "BINANCE:BTCUSDT",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "dark",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "hide_top_toolbar": true,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "save_image": false,
  "studies": [
    "DoubleEMA@tv-basicstudies"
  ],
  "container_id": "tradingview_0a8c1"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

am using the python code above with HTML code to get a screenshot of the trading chart from the HTML file, but problem is that I don't get an image for the chart, any help thx.